# How to control object in multiple zul files

Tags: zk, zul

I need to control a gmaps (in `gmaps.zul` file) from a button in another zul file (`top.zul`).
Both files are included in `root.zul`.
When I push my button ZK show me a popup error message: "`Name is empty or target is null.`"
Here's my code:

**root.zul **

```xml
<?link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/css/style.css"?>
<zk>
    <borderlayout hflex="1" vflex="1">
        <north height="100px" border="none" >
            <include id="northPanel" src="/top.zul"></include>    
        </north>
        <center id="mainContent" autoscroll="true">
            <include src="/gmaps.zul" ></include>    
        </center>
    </borderlayout>
</zk>
```

**gmaps.zul **

```xml
<zk>
    <div>
        <gmaps id="map" width="500px" height="500px" lat="35" lng="-110" />
    </div>
</zk>
```

** top.zul **

```xml
<zk>
    <div apply="test.TestComposer">
        <button id="btn" label="add marker" />
    </div>
</zk>
```

** TestComposer.java **

```java
public class TestComposer extends GenericForwardComposer {
    private Gmaps map;
    private double lat = 35;
    private double lng = -110;

    public void onClick$btn() {
        Events.echoEvent("onAddMarker", map, null);
    }

    public void onAddMarker$map() {
        Gmarker marker = new Gmarker();
        lat += 0.001;
        lng += 0.001;
        marker.setLat(lat);
        marker.setLng(lng);
        marker.setParent(map);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wire your map:

```
@Wire
private Gmaps map;
```

Comment: can you try this in your code: **map= (Gmaps ) getFellow("map");**

Comment: anywhere in your java class that needs to access map

Comment: The object is always null also if I apply getFellow() method.

Comment: oh, then you haven't applied the composer to the correct zul, apply to gmaps.zul

Comment: I solved my problem. I need to use Path.getComponent() to recover the correct instance of my variable.

Comment: please add your solution to your question

Comment: I need to add <?page id="mainPage" ?> in index.zul and then in TestComposer.java, I recover the correct istance of my object using gmaps = ((Gmaps) Path
    .getComponent("//mainPage/centerPanel/mapWin/gmaps"));g